# Unable to SSH to uploaded Ubuntu VHD on Azure

Tags: server, virtualbox, ssh, virtualization, azure

I was provided an **ova** Ubuntu 32-bits VirtualBox image, and I uploaded it to Azure using the following steps:

1. Loaded it on VirtualBox then saving it into a VMDK disk
2. Converted it to VHD format
3. Resized it to whole numbered MBs in multiples of 1024MB
4. Use Azure powershell to upload to my storage container
5. Create image
6. Create Ubuntu VM based on the image, and create cloud service
7. Provision and start the VM. Port 22 to SSH is open.

Now when I try to SSH to the client, putty opens the shell to the url and port, but I can't connect to it - the shell is totally empty and doesn't prompt for any credentials or prints anything.

I'm wondering if there's a sysprep (Windows) equivalent that I needed to do on Ubuntu, or if I've missed out any steps. Please help.

Comment: Can you console in? Is the IP address of the image consistent with the network it's connected to ie. can you ping out from it?

Comment: cant ssh in. the shell is completely empty. ip is external and consistent. All my other VMs spun fresh from Azure works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you need to open SSH port in Azure firewall setting for that machine.

On https://portal.azure.com Go to `Security zones` setting, select security zone assigned for that VM - `Inbound Security rules` - Add (`+` symbol) - Set `priority 1000`,`Source - Any`, `Protocol TCP`, `Source port range *`, `Destination port range 22`, `Action Allow` and press `Save` at the top.